# Change row id without corrupting auto increment sqlite

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I have a sqlite table with 10 rows. The structure is like this :

```
--------------------
id - Name - Address
1  - John - LA
2  - Mike - CA
      ...
---------------------
```

I want to change the last row id ( id = 10 ) to ( id = 2 ) and change the second ow ( id = 2) to be the last row ( id = 10) without corrupting Auto increment so When I Insert new row it doesn't break or start over.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Can you update the values in both lines?

Comment: Don't mess with an auto increment column. Just don't.

Comment: Yes but the the table has 14 columns it won't be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is all about the *largest* value used in the table, so you can simple use some *small* value that you know is not otherwise used:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE MyTable SET rowid = -12345 WHERE rowid = 10;
UPDATE MyTable SET rowid = 10     WHERE rowid = 2;
UPDATE MyTable SET rowid = 2      WHERE rowid = -12345;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank You!. It works fine. I just had to add `COMMIT;` at the beginning of the query to avoid error : `cannot start a transaction within a transaction: BEGIN;` Thanks again

Comment: Well, you should know whether you have already started a transaction. (Except in Python, which [tries to be clever](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions).)